# How to correctly use polymorphism to call methods of the right class in Java

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Suppose that I have a movie theater registration system.

And that I have a parent `Customer` class and a child `MinorCustomer` class.

`MinorCustomer` has a `isAuthorized()` method, ***which is not present in Customer***, that returns true or false, meant to be called if the selected movie is not for unaccompanied minors

Now, when instantiating the classes to store the information in a data structure (whichever), I run into the issue that I cannot call `isAuthorized()` in the event that the client is a minor.

This is all hypothetical so there's no program with this code, but assuming the case would be

```
Customer cust = new Customer()
if(cust.getAge() < 18) {
    cust = (MinorCustomer) cust;
    cust.isAuthorized();
}
```

However, that code would not be valid, since it would still consider `cust` to be an instance of `Customer`, not `MinorCustomer`. I know that I could simply use an if statement to determine if I want to create a new instance of Customer/Minor depending on the age, but I'd like to take advantage of polymorphism to seamlessly change the type without having to write more rigid code.

Comment: *Polymorphism* goes with a unified API combined with adapted implementation. If "being authorized" is an attribute of just one kind of customer then maybe this is not the place to count on the benefits of polymorphism. At the same time, you should ask yourself, *is being authorized really a question for minor clients only?* Does it not apply to *all customers*, with `true` being the default answer?

Comment: @ernest_k the specific case is merely hypothetical, I think a better example might be a system that has different type of loyalty programs, like gold, platinum, silver and such. different programs would have access to different types of methods, but they'd all be children of a "customer" class

Comment: The problem here is that MinorCustomer shouldn't properly be a subclass of Customer. Typically a subclass is less restricted than the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CustomerFactory` that gives a customer of the appropriate type based on an age parameter instead.

Relying on the principle that

```
class Customer { }
class MinorCustomer extends Customer { }
```

...then an implementation of your factory could be:

```
class CustomerFactory {
    public static Customer createInstance(final int age) {
        if(age < 18) {
            return new MinorCustomer();
        } else {
            return new Customer();
        }
    }
}
```

...which can then be used in your code like so.

```
Customer cust = CustomerFactory.createInstance(17);
```

You can enforce `instanceof` checks in methods that *require* that the `Customer` is not a `MinorCustomer`, or you can do an age check on the customer since you can get that information for free anyway.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the "Customer Cust" part, wouldn't that mean the resulting item will be of type Customer, leading us back to square 1 about not being able to call methods of the child class?

Comment: Yes, but the idea behind polymorphism is that each class has a *common* set of methods as opposed to specific methods for a given instance.  This is why you're going to want to rethink how you're setting this up; if you need to accept `Customer`s then your `Customer` should be capable of relaying information about itself so that any downstream code can determine if it is or isn't a `MinorCustomer`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a key concept here: that a customer is a customer. Whether it's minor, gold, major, silver, credible, bankrupt; it's a customer. This is part of basic OOP object identification, in my opinion.

Behind these sentences that state the obvious is a fundamental concept: you must have a definition of "customer" and whatever you call customer must meet it, although it may remain free to choose "how" they meet it.

Now, to make that practical: if you have a `Customer` class that is extended by `MinorCustomer` and other sub-classes, you need to declare the common behavior that's applicable to all customers in the `Customer` class. Polymorphism hinges on this. If a "customer" knows of nothing like "is authorized", then you can't introduce polymorphic "is authorized" behavior.

To use an example:

```
class Customer {
    final int getAge() {
        //return
    }
    boolean isAuthorized() {
        return true;
    }
}
class MinorCustomer extends Customer {
    private boolean parentPresent;

    @Override
    boolean isAuthorized() {
        return this.parentPresent;
    }
}
```

In the above code, the "definition" of a "customer" includes the concept of "being authorized". A "minor customer", however, is free to choose "how" it meets that definition.

It's as simple as that, you need your `Customer` API to declare the `isAuthorized()` method, and have that overridden in `MinorCustomer`. This, of course, may be inadequate for your design; and that's fine: it would simply mean that the place is not right for polymorphic behavior (and perhaps also that the inheritance relationship should be questioned).

And you can extend this reasoning to other examples as well, the parent-to-child relationship must include the declaration of behavior in the parent for polymorphism to be applicable.

As for the mechanics of cleanly creating related objects, [Makoto's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61650029/5761558) gives a good approach.

Comment: I'm just looking at this from the perspective of the "loyalty program" example.
A Customer who isn't part of a loyalty program would have no use for accumulated points, exclusive items to access, exclusive permissions.

Therefore, it makes sense to create a new GoldCustomer class that extends Customer, because then we can have those extra features. But while handling the registration, it would be necessary to determine at which point do we decide the customer in question is of type GoldCustomer

Comment: @Elmambo2194 The point I'm making, to use your example, is that there is a proper distinction between a `GoldCustomer` and a `BronzeCustomer`, but there is no proper distinction between either of these and `Customer`. At some point in your process, you need to treat a customer as a `GoldCustomer`, because the code is handling access to exclusive permissions. In other words, the process determines when you need to cast/extend. You'll create a more specific customer *when you know that the special traits apply*. This is not needed in registration, but it is needed for allocating gold benefits.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add isAuthrorized property in Customer class.

and logic should like this

```
    Customer cust = new Customer(...);
    if(cust.getAge() > 18){
      //skip authorization
      cust.isAuthrorized = true;
    }else{
      authorize.user(cust);
      //set isAuthrorized in authorization class based on user authentication fail or not
    }
```

Comment: OP mentioned that the actual type depends on the age of the customer.

Answer (score -1):

Sample in C#

```
 abstract class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Surname { get; private set; }

    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public Customer(string id, string name, string surname)
    {
        Id = id;

        Name = name;

        Surname = surname;
    }
    public abstract bool IsAuthorized();
}

class MajorCustomer : Customer
{
    public MajorCustomer(string id, string name, string surname):base(id, name, surname)
    {
            
    }
    public override bool IsAuthorized()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class MinorCustomer : Customer
{
    public MinorCustomer(string id, string name, string surname) : base(id, name, surname)
    {

    }
    public override bool IsAuthorized()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class Factory
{
    public static Customer CreateCustomer(int age, string id, string name, string surname)
    {
        if (age < 18)
        {
            return new MinorCustomer(id, name, surname);
        }
        else
        {
            return new MajorCustomer(id, name, surname);
        }
    }
}






class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer customer = Factory.CreateCustomer(21, "15612342", "Bob", "Snow");

        if(customer.IsAuthorized())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer is authorized");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer is not authorized");
        }
    }
}
```